# Angular material table add dynamic column headers

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm currently using a package inside an Angular project that houses reusable components I've developed for the project. How can I make the column headers/rows on a material table dynamic so that I can simply pass them as an input array when I consume the table inside my Angular project?

Some of these headers are stacked or have unique HTML/CSS, which is where I'm running into the issue. I've tried creating an array inside my component that has a boolean flag stating whether or not a column header/row should house two fields stacked on top of each other.

Below is a snippet from my current HTML that isn't dynamic. You can see that both ng-containers are different. How can i write this in such a way that when i consume my table inside my project, i can simply pass an array of columns/rows as an input?

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="from">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <div [ngStyle] = "{'color': pickupHeader}"  class = "stackedColumn">
        <span (click)="toggleDates($event)">{{ 'shipperFrom' }}</span>
      </div>
      <div [ngStyle] = "{'color': deliveryHeader}" class = "stackedColumn">
        <span (click) = "toggleDates($event)">{{ 'shipperTo' }}</span>
      </div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <div>
        <span class = "location"> <img src="{{ element.Flag }}">{{element.PickupCity}}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class = "location"><img src="{{ element.Flag }}">{{element.DeliveryCity}}</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="legs">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ somethingElse }} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.SomethingElse}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Basically I want to do something in my component.ts that looks like this:

```
data = [{},{},{},{}]
```

and I want that array of objects to populate the table and know what kind of HTML it should use so that when I import it and consume it in my project this is all I need:

```
<the-table [dataSource] = "data"></the-table>
```

Essentially I want to be able to add columns/rows to the table on the fly without having to go back and edit the package.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar.  Keep in mind I messed with the below a little bit to strip out some project specific details, so let me know if there are issues.

component.html:

```
<mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns; index as i" [matColumnDef]="column">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="col-search" fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayout="column">
            <span mat-sort-header>{{ getColumnLabel(column) }}</span>
            <!--The below is incomplete Just remove if you don't need filtering--> 
            <input
                matInput
                autocomplete="off"
                id="{{ column + i }}"
                (keyup)="myCustomFilterCode()" 
                placeholder="Filter"
            />
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row[column] }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!--This ngStyle is specifically for fixedWidth tables which are meant to be horizontally scrollable-->
    <mat-header-row [ngStyle]="{ 'min-width.px': width ? width : null }" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row [ngStyle]="{ 'min-width.px': width ? width : null }" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"> </mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" showFirstLastButtons [pageSize]="startingPageSize"></mat-paginator>
```

component.ts

```
/**This component will dynamically create a mat-table for a set of data */
@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-mat-table',
    templateUrl: './dynamic-mat-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dynamic-mat-table.component.scss'],
    providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class DynamicMatTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    /**The data to generate a table for */
    @Input()
    tableData: Object[];

    /** This will override the column names in the table, the id will be the property name (i.e. propertyID)
     * and the value will be the column header text 
     *
     *  **This is Only Necessary if you don't like the Automatically created column names**
     */
    @Input()
    columnLabels: IdValuePair[];

    /**List of column property names (i.e. propertyID) to ignore */
    @Input()
    ignoreColumns: string[];

    /**Sets the starting page size for the paginator */
    @Input()
    startingPageSize: number;

    /**Sets the page size options for the paginator */
    @Input()
    pageSizeOptions: number[];

    /**Defaults to false, when true the table will be generated with a width of # of columns * columnWidth,
     * otherwise column widths will not be specified (will fill container with equal width columns) */
    @Input()
    fixedWidth = false;

    /**Defaults to 250, Only used when fixedWidth = true if not set this determines the width of each column */
    @Input()
    columnWidth = 250;

    width: number;
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Object>();
    fullColumnLabels: IdValuePair[] = [];
    displayedColumns: string[];
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true })
    paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true })
    sort: MatSort;

    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    /**Generate dynamic table whenever inputs change */
    ngOnChanges() {
        this.initTable();
        if (this.tableData && this.tableData.length > 0) {
            this.displayedColumns = Object.keys(this.tableData[0]);
            this.removeIgnoredColumns();
            this.createLabelsForColumns(this.displayedColumns);
            this.calculateRowWidth(this.displayedColumns.length);
            this.dataSource.data = this.pipeData([...this.tableData]);
        }
    }

    /**Create the labels array for each column */
    private createLabelsForColumns(columns: string[]) {
        this.fullColumnLabels = this.columnLabels;
        if (this.fullColumnLabels === undefined) {
            this.fullColumnLabels = [];
        }
        if (this.tableData && this.tableData.length > 0) {
            columns.forEach(x => {
                if (!this.fullColumnLabels.some(label => label.id === x)) {
                    this.fullColumnLabels.push(new IdValuePair(x, _.startCase(x)));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**Remove ignored columns to prevent from being displayed */
    private removeIgnoredColumns() {
        if (this.ignoreColumns) {
            this.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumns.filter(x => !this.ignoreColumns.some(y => y === x));
        }
    }

    /**Calculate the row width by the number of columns */
    private calculateRowWidth(columnNumber: number) {
        if (this.fixedWidth) {
            this.width = columnNumber * this.columnWidth;
        }
    }

    /**Initialize table */
    private initTable() {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }

    /**Cleans up data with pipes if necessary*/
    private pipeData(data: Object[]): Object[] {
        data = this.pipeDates(data);
        return data;
    }

    /**Pipe dates through a date pipe if the property name contains 'date' and the value looks like a date*/
    private pipeDates(data: Object[]): Object[] {
        // ISO_8601 is what .net core returns, may need to expand this list
        const formats = [moment.ISO_8601];
        // Loop through each row of data
        data.forEach((row, index) => {
            // Loop through each property in each row
            Object.keys(data[index]).forEach(propertyName => {
                // Get the value of the property
                const value = data[index][propertyName];

                // If the value matches a format in the format list, then transform it to a short date
                if (propertyName.toLowerCase().search('date') !== -1 && moment(value, formats, true).isValid()) {
                    data[index][propertyName] = this.datePipe.transform(value, 'short');
                }
            });
        });
        return data;
    }

    /**Gets the label for a given column from the property name */
    getColumnLabel(column: string): string {
        return this.fullColumnLabels.find(x => x.id === column).value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, read your post closer and realized you're having a bigger problem, so this probably won't help much.  But I'll leave it here in case there's anything useful.